# Can I post a new topic on a google group using Go?

Tags: email, go, gmail, google-groups

I'm writing a program that should send emails to multiple users with content extracted from an excel spreadsheet. I know how to do this using the net/smtp package in Go, but I would like to know if it's possible to send an email with the sender being a google group (i.e googlegroup@gmail.com) instead of my email without resorting to using the gmail API? Currently I have a working program that can log in through an email and password, which is then used for auth credentials, but seeing as that google groups don't have the same kind of interface I'm not quite sure how to change it so emails are sent from a group instead of an individual user.

Answer (score 2):

Each google group should have an email address associated with it. [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) is `golang-nuts@googlegroups.com` for example. Any mail sent to that should be posted to the group, assuming it is from a member of the group.

In order to send from your own gmail account, you can use gmail's outgoing smtp feature with the net/smtp package. Configuration is explained better [on this digital ocean post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server)

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link (I was following another one that is slightly different). Do you know if it's possible to send unique emails to individual members of a group, but from the group itself using Go? What I mean is say that one email has content specifically directed for one user in the golang-nuts group, and another emails has slightly different content. Could I send an email where the "sender" header is golang-nuts@googlegroups.com instead of my email?